# Can we provide a bound of the inverse of a matrix plus identify?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, covariance

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300934/inverse-of-sum-of-scalar-times-matrix-plus-identity-matrix), but instead of finding the exact solution to $(A + I)^{-1}$ where $A$ is a symmetric PSD matrix, I need to somehow find an upper bound for $(A + I)^{-1}$. I am wondering if such a bound is possible to compute?

What I am ideally looking for is an element-wise upper bound on $A^{-1}$. So for example if $\;(A + cI)^{-1} \leqslant A^{-1}$ holds for all $\,c\,$, that would suffice. Moreover, does this generalise beyond the identity matrix, e.g. $\,(A + B)^{-1}\leqslant A^{-1}$ for any PSD matrix $B$ ?

Comment: Hello! Do you mean an upper bound in norm? What have you tried?

Comment: An upper bound of the norm can be found using the positive eigenvalues of $A+I$, that are the reciprocal of those of $(A+I)^{-1}$

Comment: Sorry I should have added this, I have updated the question.

Comment: It is indeed true that if $(A + B)^{-1} \leq A^{-1}$

Comment: Under what assumptions about B? PSD? Or can this be even more general?

Comment: @Q $A$ needs to be positive definition and $B$ needs to be positive semidefinite.

Comment: You cannot expect $(A+cI)^{-1}\le A^{-1}.$ For $c$ such that $A+cI>0$ the inequality holds if and only if $c\ge 0.$ So it does not hold for $-\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}<c<0.$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Is there a proof for this you could point me to?

Comment: Can the bound be tighter if $B = cI$?

Comment: @Qazaz I don't have a reference or link, but in brief:
$$
P \geq Q \implies \\
I \geq P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2} \implies\\
I \leq P^{1/2}Q^{-1}P^{1/2} \implies\\
P^{-1} \leq Q^{-1}.
$$

Comment: @Qazaz see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1602936/81360)

Comment: @Qazaz I just realized I misinterpreted your question: $(A +B)^{-1} \leq A^{-1}$ works as a Loewner bound, not necessarily as an entrywise upper bound. We know that $A^{-1} - (A + B)^{-1}$ is positive semidefinite, but not that it has non-negative entries.